# ARM HYPERVISOR: Execute single instruction and trap (equivalent of Intel's MTF)

Tags: arm, hypervisor, assembly-trap

I'm implementing a hypervisor on ARM and I need to know if there's a way to resume (**ERET**) the guest and **trap after a single instruction execution, without depending on the debug architecture (v7.1)**. I could use a software approach by modifying the next instruction of the guest to a **HVC** (equivalent of **VMCALL** on Intel), but I don't know how to handle instructions that cause branching (**JMP**).

On Intel I could use either the **trap flag** (=**TF** bit in **RFLAGS**, per-OS-thread-context) or the **monitor trap flag** (=**MTF**, **VT-x** feature).

Thank you

**EDIT: Clarifications**

- I want to avoid disassembly/emulation (as much as possible)

Comment: If you have a hypervisor, you should have the debug too. Why you don't want to use it?

Comment: Place two `HVC` instructions, one after the branch instruction and one at the branch target?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky because it implies complication of the hypervisor code; that is: 1. CPU must be put in debug state temporarily (performance issues?) 2. If I trap debug exceptions I'm also bound to trap CP14 reads/writes, debug ROM access, debug OS related register access so I'd have to emulate those too (performance issues here as well)..

Comment: @tangrs I want to avoid disassembly/emulation of guest code